# Multiple locations on iPhone MapKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

I'd like to have a feature in my app where you could allow current location and see everyone on a map that has also allowed current location in the same app.

Any ideas how to do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your web server for your application and write, at least, two apis, one to send user's location on server and other to get all users' locations.

When user will start using your application and allow application to use location services, send user's coordinate to the server.

And to show nearby users, hit api to get all user's location/(coordinates) from the server and draw them on the map.